# Converting to System time in long query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a query that includes two DateTime columns.
I saw that one can use

```
    select CONVERT_TZ(utc_timestamp(),'+00:00','SYSTEM');
```

to convert the DateTime to the system time. But I'm not entirely sure how to incorporate that into a longer query.
The query I am attempting to convert to System time is:

```
    SELECT appointmentId AS 'Appointment ID', customer.customerId AS 
    'Customer ID', customer.customerName AS 'Customer Name', type AS 
    'Type',start AS 'Start Time', end AS 'End Time'
    FROM appointment, customer
    WHERE customer.customerId = appointment.customerId  AND start BETWEEN 
    NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! I am still a noob at this.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the docs (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) for that function? Which column(s) are you trying to convert using this function - `start` and `end`? What format are they saved in - DateTime or Timestamp? I'm guessing you'll want something like `SELECT ..., CONVERT_TZ(start,'+00:00','SYSTEM') as 'Start Time', ...`

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones I tried your suggesting (and yes reviewed that document). But it didn't return any rows. The start and end columns are datetime.

Comment: `SELECT
 a.appointmentId AS 'Appointment ID',
 c.customerId AS 'Customer ID',
 c.customerName AS 'Customer Name',
 type AS 'Type',
 CONVERT_TZ(a.start,'+00:00','SYSTEM') as 'Start Time',
 CONVERT_TZ(a.end,'+00:00','SYSTEM') AS 'End Time'
FROM
 appointment a 
 JOIN customer c ON c.customerId = a.customerId
WHERE
 a.start BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);` was the full query I mean. If _no_ rows were returned, then something with the `WHERE` is incorrect. Are you sure there are any appointments with `start` between now and 7 days from now? I'd start debugging there.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones I think I got it figured out. You were right, there were no appointments within 7 days.